# overflow:hidden is not working on last li from ul

Tags: html, css, menu, overflow, css-position

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //QUALITY CONTROL
  $('#quality-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())? >resources/img/homepage/qc.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".quality-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#quality-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/qc.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".quality-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //PRODUCTION
  $('#production-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/production.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".production-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#production-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/p.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".production-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //CHEMICAL LABORATORY
  $('#laboratory-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/laboratory.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".laboratory-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#laboratory-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/cl.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".laboratory-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //LOGISTICS
  $('#logistics-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/logistics.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".logistics-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#logistics-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/logistics.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".logistics-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //REPORTS
  $('#reports-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/reports.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".reports-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#reports-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/rep.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".reports-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //INVOICE
  $('#invoices-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/in.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".invoice-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#invoices-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/in.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".invoice-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //WAREHOUSE
  $('#warehouse-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/warehouse.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".warehouse-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#warehouse-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/mr.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".warehouse-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //QUOTATIONS
  $('#quotations-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/quotation.hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".quotation-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#quotations-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/quotations.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".quotation-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //CUSTOMER SERVICES
  $('#customer-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/customer (1).hover.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".customer-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#customer-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/cs.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".customer-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });


  //CMA
  $('#cam-icon').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/cma.hover (1).png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".cam-li").addClass("hover-effect");
  });

  $('#cam-icon').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/cma.png");
    $(this).parents(".icons").prevAll("#text-circle").find(".cam-li").removeClass("hover-effect");
  });

});
```

```css
#pie_menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#icon-circle {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2222;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#text-circle {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #005B89;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#outline-circle {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  width: 515px;
  height: 515px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skewY(18deg) rotate(20deg);
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.text p {
  color: white;
}

li:first-child {
  transform: rotate(0) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(36deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(72deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(108deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(144deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(216deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(252deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(288deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(324deg) skewY(-18deg);
}

li .icon {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.circle_over {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 33333;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -135px;
  margin-left: -135px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle_over img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -65px;
  margin-left: -70px;
}

.section-icon {
  width: auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.resize45 {
  height: 45px;
  width: auto;
}

.resize65 {
  height: 65px;
  width: auto;
}

.right-padding {
  padding-right: 18px;
}

.right-padding-text {
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.left-padding-text {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

.hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  /*-webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);*/
  /*transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);*/
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
}

.hvr-icon-pulse-grow .hvr-icon {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:hover .hvr-icon,
.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:focus .hvr-icon,
.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:active .hvr-icon {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-icon-pulse-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-icon-pulse-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.hover-effect {
  background-color: #eb775f;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="pie_menu" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <div id="text-circle">
        <ul>
          <li class="production-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="right-padding-text"><b>PRODUCTION</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="logistics-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="right-padding-text"><b>LOGISTICS</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="center-block laboratory-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="right-padding-text"><b>CHEMICAL<br> LABORATORY</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="center-block quality-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="rotate left-padding-text"><b>QUALITY<br> CONTROL</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="reports-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="rotate left-padding-text"><b>REPORTS</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="invoice-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="rotate left-padding-text"><b>INVOICE</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="warehouse-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="rotate left-padding-text"><b>WAREHOUSE</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="quotation-li">
            <div class="text ">
              <p class="right-padding-text"><b>QUOTATION</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="center-block customer-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="right-padding-text"><b>CUSTOMER<br> SERVICES</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="cam-li">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="right-padding-text"><b>CAM</b></p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!--  <div id="outline-circle"></div> -->

      <div class="text-center icons">
        <ul id="icon-circle">
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=production">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="production-icon">
                <img alt="production" class="section-icon right-padding hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/p.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=shipping">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="logistics-icon">
                <img alt="logistics" class="section-icon right-padding hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/logistics.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=monitor">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="laboratory-icon">
                <img alt="laboratory" class="resize45 right-padding hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/cl.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=qualitycontrol">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="quality-icon">
                <img alt="quality" class="section-icon rotate right-padding hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/qc.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=reports">
              <div class="text icon  hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="reports-icon">
                <img alt="reports" class="rotate right-padding resize65 hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/rep.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=invoices">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="invoices-icon">
                <img alt="invoices" class="rotate right-padding resize65 hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/in.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=materials">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="warehouse-icon">
                <img alt="warehouse" class="resize45 rotate right-padding hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/mr.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=quotations">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="quotations-icon">
                <img alt="quotations" class="section-icon right-padding hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/quotations.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=cs">
              <div class="text icon hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="customer-icon">
                <img alt="customer_services" class="right-padding resize65 hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/cs.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>?tab=cam">
              <div class="text hvr-icon-pulse-grow" id="cam-icon">
                <img alt="cam" class="section-icon right-padding hvr-icon" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/homepage/cma.png" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="circle_over">
        <img alt="atlas-logo" style="width: 140px;" src="<?php print(base_url())?>resources/img/atlas-transparent.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am making a circular menu. When I hover over an icon I wanna affect some changes on the icon itself and the section with the text that is above the icon. I have two problems, both with overflow. 
1. On the circle with the icons, the last li (CAM) doesn't work properly (it covers the first li (PRODUCTION)) and when I hover over PRODUCTION icon affects on CAM section. All the other li icons work perfectly (I have applied the same styling everywhere). 
2. On the circle with the text, overflow:hidden is not working as well, cuz it should apply changes only on the text section above the icon that is hovered. Now is applying changes on the section above the icon and the one next to it.

I included pictures for better understanding.

[First problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJqz2.png)
[Second problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip045.png)

With overflow:hidden I've tried setting z-index on every li, each one bigger than the previous one, but the problem stays the same.

Comment: Pictures are missing due to indentation issue? And a jsfiddle demo would be much better.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mini_mona/cm148va7/

Comment: A StackSnippet would be preferred to a fiddle.